# problem with tensorflow and keras detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a problem with tensorflow and keras, and it doesn't detect them and this error appears, what can I do?
[image]

I already installed the pip and it still gives me that error the version that I use is python 3.8.2 of 64 bits and I use visual code to read it

Comment: what tf version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you select the same version of python that you used `pip` with in vs code

[image]

[image]